# Factoring a quadratic function

Tags: factoring, quadratic-forms

Suppose you have a vector of variables $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function defined by $h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_ix_j$, where $c_{ij}$ are rational numbers. My questions are, is it possible to write $h$ as the product of two linear functions $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_ix_i$ and  $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i$, such that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$? And if so, how do you renover the coefficients $\pi_i$ and $\alpha_i$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you factor $x^2+y^2$ in this way?

Comment: @amd: what about $(x+iy)(x-iy)$ ? ($\pi_i$ and $\alpha_i$ were not restricted to $\mathbb R$ ;) If they are restricted to $\mathbb Q$, $x^2-2y^2$ is also a counterexample.

Comment: That’s a question for the OP: are the coefficients of the factors restricted to $\mathbb R$ or even $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: The coefficients of the factors were suppose to be limited to $\mathbb{Q}$. But I get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be the matrix of your quadratic form $h$ : $M=(c_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n}$, such that if $X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix}$,
$$h(x)={}^tXMX$$
What you are asking can be translated in : $M$ is of rank $1$. So all the columns have to be proportional. If one of these columns, say $C_1$, is non null, then all the others have to be of the form $C_j=\lambda_j C_1$.

Now this means $M={}^t\Lambda \Gamma$, where $\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $\Gamma=\begin{pmatrix}\gamma_1 \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_n\end{pmatrix}$, you can choose 
$$f(X)={}^t\Lambda X\text{ and }g(X)={}^t\Gamma X$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't represent $n^2$ numbers from $2n$ numbers (unless $n\le2 $.)